# How to create a very specific kind of joint in Farseer?

Tags: xna, farseer-physics-engine

**Edit**

Problem solved (see Drackir's answer). [Here's a demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZ7e0jegvs0) of what I was trying to achieve with this joint. More info about the scenario on this [other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21143/how-to-create-a-2d-region-where-sprites-are-automatically-wrapped).

---

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a very specific type of joint in Farseer that behaves like this:

- Objects should always keep the *same* distance between them in **both** the X and Y axes.
- Translation - A collision with one of the objects should move the entire group together, but the *group must not rotate* - only the individual objects may rotate around their centers as a result of torque.
- Rotation - Objects should always have the same rotation. A collision with one of the objects should make all others rotate the exact same amount.

Here's a picture:

[image]

If there's no way to achieve this with Farseer out of the box, how would I go about extending it to create a new type of join that works like this? Basically I want every body to behave like a "clone" of the others, but with a fixed offset between them.

Comment: I'm not sure about this particular system, but can't you just turn off kinematics for the "ghost" and move/rotate it manually?

Comment: Wouldn't that also disable collisions on the ghost? Maybe ghost wasn't the best analogy for it - perhaps a clone.

Comment: I.e. collisions with the clone should affect the main body as well (in the exact same way). Would your suggestion work in that case?

Comment: Beats me, probably not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after about two hours of tinkering I managed to do this but it requires adding some extra bodies. You'll probably want to extract this stuff into a method/class but the basic idea is this:

1. Create what I call "holder" bodies for your objects. These bodies
   share the size and position of your "objects" but don't participate
   in collisions. Essentially, they are clones.

   ```cs
   //Create "Main" (center) body
   _bodyMain = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(World, 5f, 5f, 1f);
   _bodyMain.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
   _bodyMain.Position = new Vector2(2, 2);
   //Create "MainHolder"
   _bodyMainHolder = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(World, 5f, 5f, 1f);
   _bodyMainHolder.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
   _bodyMainHolder.CollisionCategories = Category.None; //Prevents collisions
   _bodyMainHolder.Position = new Vector2(2, 2);
   _bodyMainHolder.IsSensor = true;
   //See http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/222524 for why they're sensors
   _bodyMainHolder.FixedRotation = true;
   //Note: Only add FixedRotation for the main one, leave it off of the other
   //      holders. I'll explain later.
   ```
2. Attach each holder to the "mainHolder" using a `WeldJoint`. This will prevent them
   from moving away from one another. The `FixedRotation` on the mainHolder prevents
   them from rotating. I don't know if there's a bug in farseer but if you add a
   `WeldJoint` and both bodies have `FixedRotation == true`, the joint doesn't work
   properly. This is why only the main holder has `.FixedRotation = true`.

   ```cs
   //Weld the holders together so they don't move. Assumes another holder is defined
   //  for the object on the right side (bodyRightHolder).
   JointFactory.CreateWeldJoint(World, _bodyMainHolder, _bodyRightHolder,
   _bodyRightHolder.Position - _bodyMainHolder.Position, Vector2.Zero);
   ```
3. Attach your "object" bodies to their respective holders using `RevoluteJoint`s. This locks your objects to the holders but allows them to rotate freely.

   ```cs
   //Lock the actual bodies to the holders
   JointFactory.CreateRevoluteJoint(World, _bodyMainHolder, _bodyMain, Vector2.Zero);
   JointFactory.CreateRevoluteJoint(World, _bodyRightHolder, _bodyRight, Vector2.Zero);
   ```
4. Make your real objects rotations match each other by attaching an angle joint. Note: you don't have to attach an angle joint to each and every pair of objects. Just add an angle joint to the main body and the other body and the rotations will translate across all objects.

   ```cs
   //Make them rotate the same as each other
   JointFactory.CreateAngleJoint(World, _bodyMain, _bodyRight);
   ```

---

That's it! Just add the extra code for each other object/object holder you want and it will handle the rest. Here's an image to illustrate my test:[image: Example image of test bodies.]

Here you will see the green bodies are the holders. They do not rotate or collide and are welded together. The yellow and red bodies are your "objects" (yellow is the main). You can see that they are rotated by the same amount and are rotating around their respective holders. Also, only the red and yellow bodies participate in collisions. I believe this meets all three of your conditions above.

**Working Example**

If you load up the Farseer "Samples XNA" solution and find SimpleDemo1.cs ("Samples XNA" project > "Samples" folder), I rewrote it ([code here](http://pastebin.com/K6C7fd0X)) to test.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: It seems there is still one missing piece of the puzzle missing. How to *instantly* relocate the entire system to another position in the world. I need to have this to "wrap" the objects around the screen borders. Just setting the position on the main holder is not working.

Comment: Nevermind the previous question, it seems to work if relocate all holders and main bodies at the same time.

Comment: Glad to help and, yes, you'd need to relocate all bodies. You could build it into a class and store the relative positions to the main body (`Vector2` difference between the body position and the main body). Then reposition the main one and just update their positions relative to the main one.

Comment: That's pretty much what I did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot check this answer since i'm on a phone right now, so apologies if it doesn't work as I expect.

I think you could use several existing joints to achieve what you want. Create a body with no collision geometry at the corner of your triangle, you can then use three distance joints to achieve the translation you want. Then if you connect the two collidable bodies together with a fixed angle joint they will rotate together.

Comment: I'm also a bit short on time at the moment, and will give it a try tonight. But although my example only had two bodies, I will actually need something more complex than this, [with 9 connected bodies instead](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S3lzO.png). Does your idea still apply?

Comment: @David: That looks... interesting. Can you say more about what you're trying to achieve with this setup? I wonder if there might not be some alternative way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen There's a link at the end of my question to another question describing exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I'm trying to handle physics correctly in a 2D environment where bodies can "wrap" around the borders, and appear on several sides of the screen simultaneously.

Comment: @Martin I still won't have time to test this today, so I'll report back again tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, I've tried this now but couldn't get it the work. The problem is that I want to prevent the *whole system* from rotating. The 3 distance joints (which can be replaced by 2 weld joints too) keeps the system rigid but does not prevent it from rotating.

Comment: Try adding a fixed rotation joint on the central (invisible) body, to hold it at a given rotation

Comment: Also, do weld joints serve the correct purpose? I thought they prevented relative rotation of the two welded points, which is not what you want?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. You're right about the weld joints, they're not fit for this. As for your suggestions, I tried them but the problem remains - the entire system is rotating around the center body as an anchor. I'll edit my post to show you what I'm currently getting.

Comment: Hmm, I may be wrong with this, but if you attach the distance joints from the objects to the centre anchor anywhere *other* than the centre of the anchor I think that ought to prevent rotation of the system.

Comment: Was worth a try but it doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: I don't understand why that didn't work, but I do see an alternative that is guaranteed to work. If you use a prismatic joint connecting the center to the two outer ones, with the minimum and maximum limit set to the length (remember to enable joint limit) then they cannot rotate around the center, only slide within a range of 0

Comment: This also didn't work correctly. The entire system did try to keep the original rotation, but it wasn't rigid, and wobbled around until it got back to rotation 0. And the individual bodies stopped rotating around their centers. But Drackir just came up with a method that is working well.