# Torus World Collision Dection

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection

I am looking for a collision detection solution for use when 2d screen wrapping.  Specifically, when the image is split between the right and left side I can only detect a collision for a limited area.

For example, the program detects the collision when the rectangle intersects the circle in the first image.  However, it doesn't in the second image.  I am using the Rectangle.Instersects method to check for the collision in both cases.

[image: detects]

[image: Non-dection]

I used the screen-wrapping solution at the following link:
[How to create a 2D region where sprites are automatically wrapped?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21143/how-to-create-a-2d-region-where-sprites-are-automatically-wrapped)

However, since I am not using the physics engine, I am not using the related solution at:
[How to create a very specific kind of joint in Farseer?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/how-to-create-a-very-specific-kind-of-joint-in-farseer)

I am aware of the following question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679304/wrapping-drawn-image-in-xna-4-0, and incorporated part of the code to reset the draw rectangle's position when wrapping for both sprites:

```
 // reset draw rectangle for wrapping
        if (drawRectangle.X < -sprite.Width)
        {
            drawRectangle.X += parentWindowWidth;
        }
        if (drawRectangle.X > parentWindowWidth)
        {
            drawRectangle.X -= parentWindowWidth;
        }
        if (drawRectangle.Y < -sprite.Height)
        {
            drawRectangle.Y += parentWindowHeight;
        }
        if (drawRectangle.Y > parentWindowHeight)
        {
            drawRectangle.Y -= parentWindowHeight;
        }
```

This post also says that I have to check for the collision in the two separate positions, but I am having trouble doing so.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to solve this issue a long time ago, and all I did was do:

- One normal collision check.
- One where I shifted everything up one "world-height" (aka screen height)
- Shift down
- Shift left one "world-width" (screen width)
- Shift right
- Up and Right
- Up and Left
- Down and Right
- Down and Left

eg:

```
if(x + width  > test.x && x < test.x + test.width &&
   y + height > test.y && y < test.y + test.height)
{
    Collide!
}
else if(x + width  > test.x + worldWidth && x < test.x + test.width + worldWidth &&
        y + height > test.y && y < test.y + test.height)
{
    Collide!
.... 7 more times
```

Seems cumbersome and inefficient, and it probably is, but it's the easiest & most straight-forward way to solve this issue.

Below, I've drawn your playable area in **white**, and the possible collision zones in other colours in the diagram below:

[image: Torus collision example]

In this example, I have left the circle in place (x and y in example code), and compared it against your squiggle of colours in all 9 possible configurations listed above. As a visual demonstration, I've drawn all 9 possibilities.

This should get you pointed in the right direction.

Other [torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus)-world tips I can provide are:

- You're going to need to detect when an object crosses these boundaries and draw the same thing up to 4 times if it's straddling a corner.
- Shortest paths (eg, Homing missiles) will need to compare all 9 routes to the target.